# Combine calendars in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I'm looking for a program or plug-in for Outlook that will allow me to view all my calendars as one.

That is, not multiple separated/tabbed calendars, but one calendar, with events from multiple calendars.

I found http://www.exchangegroupcalendar.com/, but I'm looking for an alternative to that. Preferably free.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you just select both of the calendars on the left, then right-click and do View in Overlay Mode?

[Overlay Calendars in Outlook 2007 (like Google Calendar does)](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/overlay-calendars-in-outlook-2007-like-google-calendar-does/)

[image]

Comment: Man I dig your screenshots. I am just way to slow to even get them in.

Comment: spot on, I use overlay mode constantly

Comment: I've got a telepathic screenshot tool. =P